# Xamarin Forms XAML - create custom control that has no UI?

Tags: c#, xaml, custom-controls

Let's say I want to define some data in my XAML which I then use in multiple places in that same XAML, something like this:

```
<custom:Definition Identifier="MyTemplate">
   <custom:Data Value="3" />
   <custom:Data Value="6" />
   <custom:Data Value="12" />
</custom:Definition>

<custom:Control Template="MyTemplate" />
<custom:Control Template="MyTemplate" />
<custom:Control Template="MyTemplate" />
```

So the "Template" object doesn't show up in the UI at all, it's just data.  I was thinking I could define an object that derived from Element, like this:

```
[ContentProperty("Content")]
public class Definition : Element
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ContentProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Content), typeof(List<object), typeof(Definition), null);
    public List<object> Content { get; set; }
    public string Identifier {get; set; }
}
```

But when I do this, XAML complains "No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Content', or mismatching type between value and property".

It doesn't matter what I put for the type of the 'Content' property, or what I put in my XAML inside the  tags (even if the Definition tag has no children), I always get the same error message.

How can I add a non-UI element to a XAML?

Comment: Why would you want a XAML element with no UI though? Just make a property that's part of your code behind.

Comment: @DavidG I think the problem would be the same without XAML, if was is using in the code-behind. I guess he wants to attach some properties elements to an internal control - useful when building an app hierarchy structure or some kind of a mini-framework

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to put all my UI stuff in the XAML instead of in the code-behind so it's all in one place.  The 'custom:Definition' stuff is UI definitions that I'd rather have in the XAML so I can see both the controls and the parameters that the controls need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bindable property shouldn't be set to the shown below?

```
[ContentProperty("Content")]
public class Definition : Element
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ContentProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Content), typeof(List<object>), typeof(Definition), null);
    public List<object> Content 
    { 
        get { return (List<object>)GetValue(ContentProperty); } 
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }
    public string Identifier {get; set; }

    public Definition()
    {
        Content = new List<object>();
    }
}
```

I like your purpose. It's very reusable for many applications.

The injection of your class would be like highlighted on the image:

[image: Class injection on the Element's class hierarchy]

Comment: Yes, the property should use GetValue() and SetValue() as you describe, but making that change doesn't fix the error.

Comment: @BettyCrokker see my edit. I've forgotten to initialize the property. I've tested it here and worked. Notice that you haven't provided the code to your `Data` and `Control` classes. If it still doesn't work, share the necessary code to reconstruct your scenario and test everything needed. I hope it help you (and sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Sorry, took me a few days to get back to this ... copying your code directly got past the first error, but then I can't add it to an AbsoluteLayout without a crash.  Turns out AbsoluteLayout assumes all of its children derive from View.  So I guess I'll derive from View instead and just set my IsVisible to false.

Comment: No problems @BettyCrokker. I got it, I'm not sure about how big is your intent to use this control or the scope where it should be applicable. Maybe to keep the same idea (targeting Element) and using it **as an [Attached Property](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/attached-properties/)** instead of a control. Let me know if it fits to you and I can help with it =)